# Can we disable DFS on Windows SBS 2011?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs, windows-sbs-2011, dfs-r

The supplier of our customer's ERP system says that their software gets performance problems when running on a server with DFS enabled.

I notice that DFS Namespace and DFS Replication is enabled on the server. Can we disble those services to test if the performance problems with the software will disappear or will disabling the services give us problems?

It's a single server without any replication setup or needed.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve or is the a preemptive move? Maybe we can help with the problem?  It sounds like your software vendor is grasping at straws..

Comment: The client users get different codebase 70 errors when using the software. It looks like it has something to do with the client/server connection.

Comment: I think the only way someone here can help is if they know a bit more about your infrastructure (database type for instance would be a great place to start).  You might want to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about that?

Can't you just simply not-use-DFS? e.g. use `\\server\shared\folder` instead of `\\dfsroot\shared\folder`

I don't think that DFS by itself should have anything to do with the ERP system. You might want to check with them.

Comment: Their answer is that the ERP system has performance problems running on servers with DFS enabled.

In the next sentence they recommend to disable SMBv2 to see if the problems disappear which is against Microsoft's recommendations.

We already use \\server\shared\folder but according to the supplier it has to do with the DFS service itself. 

Do you know if we can disable those services for a test without risking major damages?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if you disable DFS on a domain controller it will get very upset, since DFS is used for sysvol replication.  Theoretically it shouldn't be necessary for a single server setup, but SBS is finnicky anyway and I reckon it would crap the bed.

You can disable SMB 2.0 on SBS 2011 and clients, no worries.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2696547

Also your supplier is talking crap, the reason their ERP program performs poorly is probably because it is poorly written.  It's not caused by DFS (how could it be?).  I'd be tempted to just tell them that you tested with DFS disabled and had the same issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the answer!

The official statement from the supplier is: "The software is built on a file database which is not compatible with the Distributed File System Replication service."

Comment: That's fine, but the DFS services won't have anything to do with their 'incompatible database' unless you are hosting the DB on a DFS share.  It won't affect it in any way.  It seems the supplier is confused.  Obviously putting a DB on a replicated shared could cause issues, but if you are not doing this then your issue must lie elsewhere.

Comment: I wouldn't run an additional database system (like an ERP system) on the SBS, it is already running multiple SQL & IIS databases of its own. I have an SBS2011 install running a Postgres database for a software package that has had problems from day 1 (4 years ago) as the SBS server was never intended to be used for it.